# Flutter Web FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am working on a Flutter web project with firebase authentication.
When I select "All exceptions" in the breakpoints tab in visual studio code I get this exception:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).

I have looked all over the place and I understand comments such as "You are probably invoking firebase before the app is initialized. All calls to firebase must come after .initializeApp(); firebase."

However if you look at my code I am not calling anything before it, the only thing coming before that is loading my environment files for api keys etc.

Here is the culprit:

```
import 'package:appname_web/app.dart';
import 'package:appname_web/bootstrap.dart';
import 'package:appname_web/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:appname_web/src/_src.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await dotenv.load(fileName: 'dotEnv.dev');
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await bootstrap(() => const App(AppEnvironment.development));
}
```

The exception does not happen at all if I don't select the "all exceptions" breakpoint

I have tried what most people suggest on Stack Overflow, but they are telling me to structure my code the same way its already structured